# Issue removing punctuation and capital letters

Tags: java, text

I am trying to read a text file and create a hash map with unique words and their frequency. I searched for a method of removing punctuation and tried implementing it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I tried using the following in the fourth line of code: line = line.replaceAll("\p{Punct}+", "");

Am I missing something?

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Book 1 A_Tale_of_Two_Cities_T.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
        while (line != null) {

            String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your word
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (m1.get(words[i]) == null) {
                    m1.put(words[i], 1);
                } else {
                    int newValue = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(m1.get(words[i])));
                    newValue++;
                    m1.put(words[i], newValue);
                }
            }
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
    Map<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(m1);
    for (Object key : sorted.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Word: " + key + "\tCounts: " + m1.get(key));
    }
```

The output I am expecting looks like this:

Word: there Counts: 279

Word: thereupon Counts: 1

Word: these Counts: 156

The issue is that I am also getting this as output:

Word: these,    Counts: 3

Word: these.    Counts: 2

Word: these.’   Counts: 1

I would like the punctuation removed from the end (and beginning) of the words and have them added to the count of "these", etc.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add an example where this code goes wrong. Add the expected and the actual output.

Comment: Your regex looks OK. What do you mean exactly by "doesn't seem to be working"? Also, you can do this task in one line of code.

Comment: @real post as answer

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I am getting and what I am expecting.  I have tried adding the regex after the while() but am getting the same output

Comment: shouldn't you replace with " " in `line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You are running your `replaceAll` after reading the first line:

```
String line = br.readLine();
line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
```

So the first line will not have any punctuation. But then, you go into this while loop:

```
while (line != null) {
    ...
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

So there is no `replaceAll` inside the loop. At its end you read another line. And then you loop back to the `while`. Since there is no replacement inside the loop, the second line and those that follow it will retain the punctuation.

The replacement should be done **inside** the loop. Moreover, it shouldn't be done right after you read the first line, because that very first line might be `null` in theory (if the file is empty).

So what you should do is do it inside the loop after you verify that the line is not null:

```
String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
    ...
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Now, it tests if the line is null, and then replaces the punctuation in it. And since the replacement is done inside the `while`, it will also be applied to the second line and those that follow it.

Comment: This fixed some of the issues I was having. All of the periods, commas, etc. are removed, but I am still getting results with dashes (-) and apostrophes... Is there a separate way to remove these?

Comment: It removes dashes and apostrophes for me. But you can try to use `[^\\p{Alpha} ]+` instead of `\\p{Punct}+` and see if that works for you, @PeteOddo . Note the space before the `]` in that expression.

Comment: @PeteOddo please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As RealSkeptic pointed out, you need to put the regex replace *inside* the loop.

There are several other "problems" with your code, but the main problem is there's just so much of it.

Here's how you can do it in one (albeit long) line:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("Book 1 A_Tale_of_Two_Cities_T.txt")
  .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "").toLowerCase()))
  .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
  .entrySet().stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
  .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Word: " + v + "\tCounts: " + v));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>